# Is it possible panic here?

Tags: go, concurrency

```
func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    anies := make(chan any)
    go doSomething(ctx, anies)
    intn := rand.Intn(2)
    if intn == 0 { //BRANCH1
        cancelFunc()
        close(anies) 
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func doSomething(ctx context.Context, anies chan any) {
    for {
         if ctx.Err() == nil { //LINE2
            anies <- 1 //LINE3
        }
    }
}
```

Can it be possible that somewhen BRANCH1 happens between LINE2 AND LINE3 and I will got panic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a panic is possible.  Here's an example timeline where a panic occurs. The lines are in increasing time order. The N: prefix represents the goroutine.

1: start goroutine 2
2: call ctx.Err(), it returns nil
1: call cancelFunc()
1: close channel anies
2: send to channel anies. panic because channel is closed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know an approach how to avoid that. Cause it's realy seems like it's very hard to build panicless concurecny app. I know this is hard, but, may be there is some patterns in this situation